# Installing QGIS on Linux Mint 15 Mate

Tags: qgis, installation, linux

I've just tried to install the latest version of QGIS on Linux Mint 15 Mate using 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get install qgis'.
However, QGIS gives me the error message 'Couldn't load PyQGIS.
Python support will be disabled.'. Also, the installed QGIS version turns out to be 1.7.5 while I would prefer 1.8.0 or even 2.0.

I am pretty new to the world of Linux in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best option if you want to work with several GIS applications and a Ubuntu-based system is the UbuntuGIS repository.
Adding it to your sources is very easy, just enter this commands in the terminal, one at a time.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis
```

After that you will have QGIS 2.0 installed in your system. There are some plugins available like the grass one wich is very useful for GRASS integration.
In my case, I had an error running QGIS without root privileges, which I solved giving permissions to the QGIS folder:

(In the /home/user folder)

```
sudo chmod -R +rwx .qgis2
```

After that it should run fine just from the application menu.